# VB.NET - Checking and Executing Updates?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So I have a very small bit of VB.NET that can check fine if theres an Update.
But theres a few issues:

It does this all while not stopping the main code from executing;

It wont even download the file;

I cant get it to close the app that found the Update/Downloaded the Update and then Open the new file.

How can I get it to do all of that?

Current Code:

```
Public Sub CheckForUpdates()

        'Connect to the Version File and Open It/Read It's Contents;
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rrk7yhfjvy500jl/version.txt")
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        'Set the Variables to the Appropriate Versions;
        Dim newestversion As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
        Dim currentversion As String = Application.ProductVersion

        'If the program isn't up to date;
        If Not newestversion.Contains(currentversion) Then

            MessageBox.Show("Downloading update!")

            'Download the Update;
            Using wc = New WebClient()

                'Download the newest EXE file and store it in the same Directory as the Current EXE file;
                wc.DownloadFile("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/da3in67jjayvqsz/PRAGMA1.exe", Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup), "PRAGMA1.exe"))

            End Using

        End If

    End Sub
```

(It doesnt work)

Comment: You cannot replace a file in use (like your app) and depending where the app is installed, you may need admin rights to save files there.  If you are going to write your own, you need to have the updater as a separate app.

Comment: @Plutonix not sure if that would be a way around it

Comment: Of course that is a way around it. Having an external application is the only way around it. ;_;

Comment: Ok I found a way around it. I just downloaded it under "update.exe" and used CMD with Process.Start to delete the Old File and rename "update.exe" to "pragma.exe" :D